# TestCafe keeps crashing on windows 10 laptop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, automation, automated-tests, testcafe

Am using testcafe 1.6.1 and other dependencies are as below

```
"gherkin-testcafe": "2.2.0",
"multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "latest",
"testcafe": "^1.6.1",
"testcafe-react-selectors": "3.0.0",
"testcafe-reporter-cucumber-json": "latest",
```

I run my tests locally from gitprompt. 7 out of 10-time testcafe keeps crashing on my windows laptop. This laptop is client-provided laptop and I have very few permission to change any browser settings. Is anyone at testcafe or from the community aware of such problem? Is there a log file that I can refer to and share it here? where is TestCafe log file present on windows laptop? Please help. Thx.

Comment: Could you please record a video illustrating the problem. You can use the [Jing](https://www.techsmith.com/jing-tool.html) tool for it.

Comment: @mlosev, sorry for late reply, but the behavior i mentioned is happening at my workplace and any sort of screen recording are prohibited and is against policy. Is there any other way to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Is there any error information in the console output? Does this issue occur with a particular test?

Comment: @DmitryOstashev- this keeps happening randomly, almost every other run. I see this  error in my git bash

Comment: ' { Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 'C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\3\testcafe\chrome-profile-396LPMzIXfMqlkW\en-US-8-0.bdic'   
  errno: -4082,                                                                           
  code: 'EBUSY',  syscall: 'unlink',   path: 'C:\\Users\\**\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\3\\testcafe\\chrome-profile-396LPMzIXfMqlkW\\en-US-8-0.bdic' }                                
{ Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink 'C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Temp\3\testcafe\chrome-profile-396LPMzIXfMqlkW\en-US-8-0.bdic''

Comment: By default, TestCafe launches browsers with a clean profile. Judging by the error, this temporary profile cannot be deleted because some process is still using it. As a workaround, you can disable this feature by adding the `:userProfile` suffix to a browser alias (see [User Profiles](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/browsers/user-profiles.html)).